# order by date format with union in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have used union with order by, In resultant table the date format is not ordering.

```
(
    select 
        DATE_FORMAT(Date_1, '%m/%d/%Y') as  first_date, 
        null as second_date,
        col_2,
        Col_3,
        col_4 from table1 where Date_1 !=''
)
union all
(
    select 
        null as first_date , 
        DATE_FORMAT(Date_2, '%m/%d/%Y') as second_date, 
        col_2, 
        null as col_3, 
        col_4
    from table1 
    where Date_2 !=''
)
order by  Date_1 desc, Date_2 desc;
```

with above i am able to retrieve records but dates are not ordered. Any Help!

Comment: you're not selecting any columns called `date_1` or `date_2`, how do you expect to be able to order by them? your date fields are called `first_date` and `second_date`

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> If a column to be sorted is aliased, the ORDER BY clause must refer to
>   the alias, not the column name.

```
    (
        select 
            DATE_FORMAT(Date_1, '%m/%d/%Y') as  first_date, 
            null as second_date,
            col_2,
            Col_3,
            col_4 from table1 where Date_1 !=''
    )
    union all
    (
        select 
            null as first_date , 
            DATE_FORMAT(Date_2, '%m/%d/%Y') as second_date, 
            col_2, 
            null as col_3, 
            col_4
        from table1 
        where Date_2 !=''
    )
    order by  first_date  desc, second_date desc;
```